# How to UNION ALL tables with dynamic column headers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to UNION ALL a bunch of tables. Most of them have the exact same structure and column headings and data types which works fine. The tables have some column headings which dynamically change each month. Most tables look like this:

Table 1:

```
  Type   2018-08   2018-09   2018-10   2018-11   2018-12  
 ------ --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- 
     1        10        16         8         4        11  
     2        17        21         6         9        14  
     3        12        12        10         5        10
```

The month columns change every month. The new month is added and the oldest month removed. The number of columns doesn't change.

The problem is when I try to UNION ALL tables which have an extra column like so:

Table 2:

```
  Type   Category   2018-08   2018-09   2018-10   2018-11   2018-12  
 ------ ---------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- 
     1   A               10        16         8         4        11  
     2   B               17        21         6         9        14  
     3   A               12        12        10         5        10
```

Normally I would just:

```
SELECT [Type], '' AS Category, [2018-08], [2018-09], [2018-10], [2018-11], [2018-12]

FROM Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT [Type], Category, [2018-08], [2018-09], [2018-10], [2018-11], [2018-12]

FROM Table2
```

The problem with this is that I would have to update the month column names manually every month.

I also have a table with a different extra column like so:

Table 3:

```
  Type   Organisation   2018-08   2018-09   2018-10   2018-11   2018-12  
 ------ -------------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- 
    11   South               15        12         6         8        18  
    13   West                14         9         9        11        16  
    21   North               10        15        13        14        16
```

I tried to:

```
SELECT '' AS Category, '' AS Organisation, *

FROM Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT Category, '' AS Organisation, *

FROM Table2

UNION ALL

SELECT '' AS Category, Organisation, *

FROM Table3
```

But this also didn't work as it was still including all columns which weren't matching up.

Is it possible to UNION ALL these tables without specifying the column names?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: You'll have to use Dynamic-SQL using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`-based reflection - this won't be pretty.

Comment: No.  A `UNION ALL` requires that all the columns be the same and have compatible types.  Your problem is your data structure -- it would be better to have a table with one row per month.

Comment: Seems like the real problem is your design. You shouldn't have a column for every month, you should have a column which has a value to denotes the month. Then, if you must, you can (dynamically) pivot the results. Fix your design and normalise your data.

Comment: It sounds like not ideal table design to make the column name variable months.  Why not just have a single date column, and extract the month from that?

Comment: Welcome to PIVOT Hell.